# Функция glfwCreateWindow из библиотеки GLFW возвращает null

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

При попытке поместить результат этой функции в указатель, в него помещается NULL.

Библиотеки:
OpenGL,
GLEW,
GLFW,
iostream

Вот весь код:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world !" << std::endl;
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "GLFW has been failed" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    if (!glewInit()) {
        std::cout << "GLEW has been failed" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glewExperimental = GLFW_TRUE;

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1110, 480, "Eternal Engine", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window) {
        std::cout << "Creating window has been failed" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 1110, 480);

    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Вот проблемный указатель с присваиванием в него функции:

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1110, 480, "Eternal Engine", nullptr, nullptr);
```

Следующие 5 строчек проверяют его на NULL:

```
if (!window) {
        std::cout << "Creating window has been failed" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
```

Как итог выводится "Creating window has been failed", то есть выполняется логика выше представленного if-а[image] и программа завершается с кодом -1

Comment: версия 3.3? такой же вроде не было.

Comment: 1) Даже если убрать glfwWindowHint, всё равно работать не будет.
2) GetError по незнанию не использую.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена удалением 15 строчки кода -> glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)